# Best way to implement Blue/Green Deployments on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, blue-green-deployment

I'm planning to do blue/green deployment on EC2 instances, currently cloudformation supports ECS/Beanstalk not EC2 instances. What is the best approach to implement this in cloudformation.

Appreciate your thoughts on this, still I'm researching on different methods.

Comment: You can use CodeDeploy for B/G.

Comment: @Marcin thanks,  I can see ComputePlatform
The destination platform type for the deployment (Lambda, Server, or ECS). assume server is EC2 Instances.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.